# Concatenating Pandas DataFrames Doubling Rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am trying to concat() two DataFrames in pandas. One of the dataframes are just some columns I have taken from the other dataframe and transformed, so at no point do I resort them. But when I try to concatenate them I get an error saying they can't be concatenated together and so they are concatenated almost diagonally with the number of rows doubling (as each has the same rows) and the number of columns increasing by columns in one plus the other.

Ideally I would like the number of rows to stay the same and the number of columns to be the columns in one plus the columns in the other. Below is my code:

```
## In the below code I create new names for the scaled fields by adding SC_ to 
## their existing names
SC_ExplanVars = []

for var in explan_vars:
    sc_var= "SC_" + var
    SC_ExplanVars.append(sc_var)

## Scale the columns from my dataframe that will be used as explanatory 
## variables
X_Scale = preprocessing.scale(data[ExplanVars])

## Put my newly scaled explanatory variables into a DataFrame with same headers
## but with SC_ infont
X_Scale = pd.DataFrame(X_Scale, columns = SC_ExplanVars)

## Concatenate scaled variables onto original dataset
datat = pd.concat([data, X_Scale], axis=1)
```

I get the warning:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py:77: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  result = result.union(other)
```

EDIT

Below is a table of what I was describing. It is only the top 10 rows and I have changed it to only one column and still seems to give me the same issue

```
Data=
    Col1
    297
    297
    297
    297
    275
    275
    275
    400
    400
    400

X_Scale = 
SC_Col1
-0.4644471998668502
-0.4644471998668502
-0.4644471998668502
-0.4644471998668502
-0.8849343767010354
-0.8849343767010354
-0.8849343767010354
1.5041973098568349
1.5041973098568349
1.5041973098568349
```

After concatenation

```
datat = 
Col1    SC_Col1
297.0   NaN
297.0   NaN
297.0   NaN
297.0   NaN
275.0   NaN
275.0   NaN
275.0   NaN
400.0   NaN
400.0   NaN
400.0   NaN
NaN -0.4644471998668502
NaN -0.4644471998668502
NaN -0.4644471998668502
NaN -0.4644471998668502
NaN -0.8849343767010354
NaN -0.8849343767010354
NaN -0.8849343767010354
NaN 1.5041973098568349
NaN 1.5041973098568349
NaN 1.5041973098568349
```

Comment: Could you show a sample of your dataframe and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's impossible to reproduce the error since you didn't say what is `explan_vars`, `data`, `preprocessing`...

Comment: Using the two dataframes you posted in the edit it works. I cannot reproduce your behaviour: I get two columns, ten rows and no NaN in my concatenated dataframe. I can only think that the problem is somewhere before. From the warning, maybe you have integers which are strings somewere.

Comment: Have you tried doing the `concat` with `ignore_index=True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be there is a different index label, try using [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) in each dataframe before concatenating:

Example i have this 2 dataframes with different index name and try to `concat` them:

```
d1={'Col1':[297,297,297,297,275,275,275,400,400,400]}
d2={'SC_Col1': [-0.4644471998668502,-0.4644471998668502,-0.4644471998668502,-0.4644471998668502,-0.8849343767010354,-0.8849343767010354,-0.8849343767010354,1.5041973098568349,1.5041973098568349,1.5041973098568349]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(d1, index=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])
df2=pd.DataFrame(d2)
print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
     Col1   SC_Col1
0     NaN -0.464447
1     NaN -0.464447
2     NaN -0.464447
3     NaN -0.464447
4     NaN -0.884934
5     NaN -0.884934
6     NaN -0.884934
7     NaN  1.504197
8     NaN  1.504197
9     NaN  1.504197
10  297.0       NaN
11  297.0       NaN
12  297.0       NaN
13  297.0       NaN
14  275.0       NaN
15  275.0       NaN
16  275.0       NaN
17  400.0       NaN
18  400.0       NaN
19  400.0       NaN
```

---

After using `reset_index()` with parameter `drop=True` before `concat()` operation, the dataframe will look like this:

```
df1=df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True)
print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   Col1   SC_Col1
0   297 -0.464447
1   297 -0.464447
2   297 -0.464447
3   297 -0.464447
4   275 -0.884934
5   275 -0.884934
6   275 -0.884934
7   400  1.504197
8   400  1.504197
9   400  1.504197
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Thanks ALFAFA, it seemed to work. Do you know how the index would have changed?

Comment: it seems that there are some white spaces before `Col1` column and nothing before `SC_Col1` column. To make sure that there is a difference of index label, you can use `data.index` and `X_Scale.index`